# return sum of all items of the array passed that lie in the number range low or high

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to understand this question a bit more. Currently I need to return the sum of all the values that lie with a range either low or high within an array. Currently I have got this far (see code below), however I am stuck on what to do next. Any help?

```
public static int sumrange(int[] data, int low, int high) {
    int sum = 0; 
    if (data == null || data.length == 0) {
           return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length;) {
        if (i < low) {
            sum = sum + data[i];
            return sum;
        }else if (i > high)
            sum = sum + data[i];
            return sum;         
    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: you want to return the sum after you are done with your loop, not inside the loop.

Comment: Well, if you ask for clarification with your assignment, you might want to talk to your peers or tutors. Regarding your implementation ... ask yourself what happens with your code when your array has 5 entries, and low is say 3. That is in general a good strategy: before writing a single line of code, think of different examples of input data. And ask yourself what would / should come out of those. And then run your code with those examples and see what happens.

Comment: You are comparing the index instead of the value in that index also you have the condition backward and it should be in single if like `data[i] > low && data[i] < high`.